# Font owner question FROSTY

Tags: adobe-indesign, font-identification, font-licensing

I have a client who wants to use a font on his bookcover called Frosty, which is quite irregular and has "snowflakes" scattered around the letters. I cannot find who has this licensed. It is not on MyFonts. Any suggestions about other places to look? I've googled myself silly.

Comment: can you please drop a screenshot here, because it can be know, but under different name

Comment: Please post a screenshot..  It could be a custom typographic font designed just for the book..  However, if we dont see a picture of what you're trying to do how can we truly help you?

Answer (score 2):

There are some Frosty fonts,

[Version 1](http://www.dafont.com/frosty.font)

[image]

[Version 2](http://www.fonts101.com/fonts/view/Uncategorized/27643/JNKSAILOR_FROSTY)

[image]

[Version 3](http://www.themadwomanoflockestreet.com/frosty-snowflake-font.php) (not a real font, just picts)

[image]

Without example we cannot be more precise.